# Selecting iPad As Audio Source When Mirroring to Apple TV?

Tags: ipad, audio, appletv, airplay, headphones

I'm currently mirroring from my iPad to my Apple TV, but the audio source automatically sets to the TV. At night I'd love it if I could switch the audio source to my ipad so I could hook up some headphones, while watching on the TV. Is this possible?

Comment: On mac os there you can specify the primary sound source (external or built-in speakers) in the sound options. Unfortunately i havent seen this option on ios.

Comment: I've been looking for this option in iOS also but could never find it. I always use it on my mac hoping that it was available with the ipad. Thanks anyway bluewoodtree!

Comment: This isn't how AirPlay is designed on iOS. Are you really looking for a no answer or are you open to people's suggestions on how to get the content you wish on a TV and the sound on another device? You might just need to buy a [pair of headphones with an infrared remote](http://www.bing.com/shopping/xovision-ir620-headphones/p/6BAFC87AAF16E96A4895?q=tv+infrared+remote+headphones&lpq=tv%20infrared%20remote%20headphones&FORM=HURE) and have them send the TV sound to your ears once it gets it from your iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with how AirPlay currently works. It's a great idea to [send to Apple for future consideration](http://www.apple.com/feedback/), however.

On my Panasonic Viera theres a headphone jack and a seperate volume setting for the headphones (so you can turn the TV right down). I've also got a set of TDK wireless headphones which do double duty (TV, iPad, iPhone). They've got line-of-sight range of about ten meters so you can move around without causing disturbance. Smaller TV's generally dont have audio out, but if you're looking to watch stuff in bed, why would you need anymore than the iPad fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy solution but I use an old Airport express plugged in next to the sofa with a pair of Bose Quiet comfort. The headphones are plugged in directly into the Airport. From the Apple tv airplay setup menu, I chose the airport express as speakers. Since the Quiet Comfort are powered headphones, this works quite well. The sound is actually amazing + noise cancellation which is pretty sweet if you have kids... Wouldn't work with non-powered headphones.